# How to organise helping functions in my code

Tags: python, architecture, code-organization

So the class I've created looks like this:

```
class DataProcessor(object):

    data1
    data2
    data3

    def process_data(self):
        self.process_data1_inOneWay()
        self.process_data2_inAnotherWay()
        self.process_data3_inADifferentWay()
```

The processing task consists of parts and my question is: **what is the proper place to define those helping functions**. I don't feel like they should be part of the `DataProcessor` class, because `process_data` is the only method that uses them. I considered defining an inner class, but I read that their usage isn't really encouraged. I also considered lambdas, but rejected this idea due to their limited functionality. Or maybe I should put all the code inside `process_data` method and don't split it into smaller parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just put them into the class and give them a weak 'internal use' indicator.

According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) those method's names should have a leading underscore: `_process_data1_someway()`.

As long as it is easily obvious what their role/intended visibility is just from reading the class definition, I would not worry too much about that.

Answer (score 3):

I would keep is simple and place the helpers in the class; it is likely where a reader of your code will expect to find them. As follows:

```
class DataProcessor(object):

    data1
    data2
    data3

    def process_data(self):
        self._process_data1_inOneWay()
        self._process_data2_inAnotherWay()
        self._process_data3_inADifferentWay()

    def _process_data1_inOneWay(self):
        pass

    def _process_data2_inAnotherWay(self):
        pass

    def _process_data3_inADifferentWay(self):
        pass
```

Please note the use of an underscore prefix to notify that these methods are used internally only (as you mentioned they were called from one point only)